# Deploy iOS program to iPhone

Tags: ios

Suppose I have written a little program by Xcode 4, how can I test this program in iPhone instead of the iOS Simulator?

Should I export the program to a file like .apk(in Android) and installing in iPhone?
Or I must sign it and upload to App Store, then install it by App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Pay Apple $99 to become a developer.
2. Get a jailbroken iPhone.

If you want it on the App Store, then you must take option 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are registered in the Apple Developer Program you can install the app in your iPhone for testing.